# Namespaced autoloading not working properly

Tags: php

I'm having trouble getting autoloading to work with namespaces. Here's the directory structure I created for this:

```
index.php
app/
  utils/
    sys/
      DirReader.php
    helpers/
      DB.php
```

The `index.php` contains the autoloader, which includes the files DirReader.php and DB.php.

Here's what the `index.php` looks like:

```
<?php

function __autoload($ns_str) //ns_str = namespace string
{
    $path = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $ns_str);
    //echo "**$path**\n";
    require_once "$path.php";
}

use \app\utils\sys as sys;
use \app\utils\helpers as helpers;

$dir = new sys\DirReader();
$db = new helpers\DB();
```

Here's `DirReader.php`:

```
<?php
namespace app\utils\sys;

class DirReader
{
    public function __construct()
    {   
        echo "DirReader object created!\n";
    }   
}
```

And here's `DB.php`:

```
<?php
namespace app\utils\helpers;

class DB
{
    public function __construct()
    {   
        echo "DB object created!\n";
    }   
}
```

The example works fine, but when I add a namespace declaration to `index.php`, it fails:

```
<?php
    namespace myns;
    function __autoload($ns_str) //ns_str = namespace string
    { /*. . .*/
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'app\utils\sys\DirReader' not found in
>   /var/www/html/php_learn/autoloading_1/index.php on line 15 PHP Stack
>   trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   /var/www/html/php_learn/autoloading_1/index.php:0

According to me this error shouldn't come because I've used absolute names when using namespaces in `index.php`. I know that saying something like `use app\utils\sys as sys;` would fail because then the namespace will be searched relative to `myns`, where nothing exists. But I don't know why my code is not working. (I also tried changing the name of the namespace in `index.php` to `autoloading_1`, the name of the containing directory, but it didn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__autoload` function must be defined in global space.
Use [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) otherwise. Use of `__autoload()` is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! But why should the `__autoload()` function not be used? Also, the manual says nothing about the fact that `spl_autoload_register()` doesn't need to be in global namespace.

Comment: I think that is something taken for granted. You can define `\myns\__autoload`, `\another_namespace\__autoload`, etc. But the only function that php can call among these is that in global space. That's why `__autoload` is restricted and discouraged. `spl_autoload_register` gives you a more flexible way to register an autoload, and  doesn't need to be in global namespace to do it.